# HAProxy FrontEnd's IP Added to Header

Tags: haproxy

Using HAProxy 1.5, is it possible to add a request header whose value is the IP address used by a frontend whose bind uses a wildcard?

For example, given the following configuration, is there something I replace "%[fe_id]" with in order to get the variable IP address that was used to connect to the frontend?

```
frontend localhost
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/ssl.pem
    mode http
    default_backend nodes
    option forwardfor

backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    http-request add-header X-FrontEnd-IP %[fe_id]
    server web00 10.1.10.15:80 check
    server web01 10.1.10.16:80 check
    server web02 10.1.10.17:80 check
```

Comment: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#option%20forwardfor

Comment: Thank you for your response. 


Sorry, let me clarify. I'm looking for the IP address used to connect to the frontend listener. 


In a more static environment, we'd bind to a specific IP address and therefore that IP address would be know. However, in this case, the HAProxy host has multiple IP addresses and we need to know which one was used in the request. Not the client's IP address, but whichever IP address HAProxy bound to in the given request.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Not sure how I missed this, but the variable is "dst". So the resulting config would look like this:

```
frontend localhost
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/ssl.pem
    mode http
    default_backend nodes
    option forwardfor

backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    http-request add-header X-FrontEnd-IP %[dst]
    server web00 10.1.10.15:80 check
    server web01 10.1.10.16:80 check
    server web02 10.1.10.17:80 check
```

This way we can see if the request came from inside or outside our network and the web server can adapt accordingly.

Furthermore, to access this variable with PHP it is as simple as using the $_SERVER array with the key "HTTP_X_FRONTEND_IP".

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FRONTEND_IP']
```